# get the ip of app server serving request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I have load balancer which routes my request to different rails app hosted on separate boxes.
I need to know the server address /Ip which served the request.

I need this as my certain request fails abruptly and i suspect that one of my server box is not behaving correctly.

Code cant be wrong as all the server has the same data disk mounted and the code running is same.

Comment: why dont you maintain a log while routing? also a rescue to log errors

Comment: Yes i do have log maintained and my error notifications are also configured which shows me generic error, nothing specific or code related. I suspect its one of the servers error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the ip address / hostname in your main application layout as a html comment if you're serving html or create rules for each host in the load balancer so that you can access them individually.

application.html.erb:

```
<!-- Host: <%= Socket.gethostname %> -->
```